# Spread Operator not working while importing from const variable

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, import, export

I am facing some weird problem while import a const value in react. Actually, I am exporting a const which is not related to react like

```
export const menu =  [{
        "icon": "si-home",
        "path": "dashboard",
        "name": "Dashboard",
        "key": "0",
        "permissionName": ["View"],
        "permission": ["off"],
        "sub": []
    }];
```

And from another component I'm importing, then I'm using the spread operator but both variables become identical even if I require again they are also identical. I guess this is something with export-import.

```
    import menu from'../../../menu ';
    const permissions = [...menu];

  //some operation on permissions ....
  permissions[0].permission[0] = 'on';
  console.log(menu);
  console.log(permissions);
```

both are identical

Comment: This is behaving exactly as it should, what are you expecting to get within `permissions` ?

Comment: You may have a look at [Spread in arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals).

Comment: @Treycos see I'm changing permission and menu should remain same but it doesn't

Comment: @bela I know-how spread operator works but it's behaving unusually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a normal behavior because you keep references. So if you mutate an object inside permissions it will also change the one in menu since they are in the same memory reference.
Maybe you should deepClone menu inside permissions if you want to mutate permission without touching menu.

Comment: I don't want deepClone to do that its something wrong with my export or spread operator

Comment: it won't work unless you deepClone because when you spread an array containing object those object keep memory reference.
you could do something like this :

`const permissions = menu.map(m => {return {...m}};`

Comment: thanks a lot, I can't afford extra library just to do that, let me try it

Comment: @thomasL: No need for `return`: `const permissions = menu.map(m => ({...m}));`

Answer (score 1):

```
export const getMenu = () => { 
    return( [{
        "icon": "si-home",
        "path": "dashboard",
        "name": "Dashboard",
        "key": "0",
        "permissionName": ["View"],
        "permission": ["off"],
        "sub": []
        }])
};
```

this will give a new Object

Comment: Please be more specific. That function will return an array.